# If condition is met -> scan input into one variable. If not -> scan input into another variable

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)

System.out.print("Enter either a string or a number");

String str = input.nextLine();
int x = input.nextInt();
```

The program here expects 2 values, a string and an integer. YET there is only one.

I want `str` to register the value if it is a string, BUT if it is an integer, I want the value to be registered by `x`

In other words, I only want one of the variables to be active

Comment: Just read it as a string and try to parse it to an int. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102916/10601203) for a few ways to check if the string is a number.

Answer (score 0):

if the value of entered is an integer, then you can simply use regex where

```
if(str.matches("\\d+") || str.matches("-\\d+"))
```

checks if the entered number is a number of 1 or more digits or the entered number is a negative number with one or more digits

and if that is the case, then you can `x = Integer.parseInt(str);` to convert that entered string into integer and make `str = "";` otherwise , the entered string is stored in `str` and never parsed to `int`

and this is the edited code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter either a string or a number\n");

        String str = input.nextLine();

        int x = 0;

        if(str.matches("\\d+") || str.matches("-\\d+"))
        {
            x = Integer.parseInt(str);
            str = "";
        }
        else
        {
            // nothing to do
        }

        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        System.out.println("str = " + str);

    }

}
```

and this is some example output:

```
Enter either a string or a number
10
x = 10
str =
```

---

```
Enter either a string or a number
test
x = 0
str = test
```

---

```
Enter either a string or a number
-30
x = -30
str =
```

---

```
Enter either a string or a number
test10
x = 0
str = test10
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by abdo and the comment by Jesse are both valid and very good answers.

However it is also possible to achieve your goal with the Scanner methods. In this case `hasNextInt()` is your friend.
f
But note, that `nextLine()` will consume the line break, while `nextInt()` will not. IMHO it will be more clear to code both options alike and use `next()` instead.

The most simple approach:

```java
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    x = input.nextInt();
}
else {
    str = input.next();
}
input.nextLine(); // consume the line break, too
```

Here still one issue remains: By default Scanner uses whitespace as delimiter, not line breaks. With the input "4 2\n" `nextInt()` will return 4 and `nextLine()` will discard the rest. However the user's intention (number versus string) is not obvious in this case either, therefor I'd tend to create the string "4 2" instead. This can easily be achieved by using line breaks as delimiter instead:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
```

A full demo example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());

        System.out.println("Enter either a string or a number");

        String str = null;
        while (!"end".equals(str)) {
            int x = 0;
            str = null;
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                x = input.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                str = input.next();
            }
            input.nextLine();
            if (str != null) {
                System.out.printf("we have a string! str=%s%n", str);
            }
            else {
                System.out.printf("we have a number! x=%d%n", x);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("goodbye!");
    }

}
```